# How do I access a Ubuntu server network when using a shared internet connection from a Windows laptop?

Tags: wireless-networking, network-shares, lan, wireless-bridge

I have a server with Ubuntu 12.04 which is accessing internet (through crossover cable) with the help of network shared by my laptop(with VISTA) connected to wifi of my home. So my laptop has two ip addresses, one is of wireless network and other is acting as a router address for my server to connect to. Server is able to access the internet and the pair is working fine.

Now, I want to connect other laptops (which are sharing the same wifi of my home) to my server. But when I ping server's ip or my laptop's router's ip, I get 'request timed out'.

How can I wirelessly connect other laptops to the network created by my Windows laptop? Do I need to do bridging between both the networks of my first laptop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to disable ICS and bridge your LAN and WAN adapters. ICS uses 2 different subnets and NAT to route traffic from one adapter to the other. This essentially means any host connecting from the shared side of the ICS box is invisible to devices on your wifi network.

A bridge remedies this problem by simply creating a logical network segment between two adapters and forwarding all packets as if they were on the same subnet.

Comment: I did the same but now both the server and my laptop has the same ip. how to connect to the server now?

Comment: I had to assign static ip to my server. Server is now part of my LAN. :-)